# Speed of Sound in 1D using pressure and density

Tags: classical-mechanics, acoustics, oscillators, string, phonons

I am trying to figure out the speed of sound in an infinite chain of 1D harmonic oscillators using the relation
$$u^2=\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}$$
I have seen multiple times the derivation using $F=ma=md^2x/dt^2$ and then fourier decompose to get the sin relation, however this approach is really messing with me.

In 1D the pressure is just the force, so $P = K(-2x_{n}+x_{n-1}+x_{n+1})$, but I am unsure of what the density is.  I would guess is it just $m/L$, but we take $L$ to be infinite, so that goes to 0.  I am curious as to what the proper density to use in this  scenario.

Comment: the density would be the mass of every particle divided by the distance between two particles.

Comment: so if its diatomic (m1--m2--m1--) the density is just the average mass/separation?

Comment: @yankeefan11 To keep units consistent, it's really mass / length / unit depth / unit height. Otherwise, you'll have to do strange things like change all of your other units in the equation. At the end of the day, yes it is just mass / length because you take the unit depth and height to be 1. But don't forget they are there.

Comment: @tpg2114 Well it cancels out the Area term from the Pressure.  So how do I treat the diatomic case in terms of density and force, seeing as I have terms that are dx/dm1

Answer (score 1):

The speed of sound in such a harmonic chain depeneds on the frequency: In a wave
$$
x_n= \sin(kn-\omega t)
$$
the angular frequency$\omega$  and wavenumber $k$ are related by
$$
\omega= 2 c \sin (k/2)
$$
where $c^2= K/m$.

Comment: I am familiar with that. However, I am asked to solve using the equation I wrote, which requires the force on each HO and the density.

Comment: I guess my point is that there is no "speed of sound" as it depends on the frequency. For long waves it is my $c$ measured in "particles passesd per second".  Your expression does not say how far apart the $x_n$ in equilibrium so we cannot convert" particles passed per second" to meters per second without that further information.

Comment: The spacing is just some lattice constant a (which is the primitive cell size).  I get the idea that you can fourier expand the xn and solve for $\omega$ as a function of some quasi momentum q and the masses.  I also know that the speed of sound is the approximation that q approaches 0, so the sin argument becomes the argument and omega is linear in q, with the proportionality the speed of sound.  What I do not see how I would get this from laplaces formula dP/dp

Comment: So the density $\rho =m/a$, the  is  speed of sound is $a \sqrt{K/m}= \sqrt{Ka/\rho}$ which makes the bulk modulus $\kappa=Ka$. Remember that the speed of sound is $c^2 =\kappa/\rho$ and $\kappa=  \rho dP/d\rho$

Comment: By the way the force is not the pressure, it is the gradient of the pressure.