# Derivation of speed of sound in (diatomic) chain using Newton-Laplace formula

Tags: classical-mechanics, condensed-matter, acoustics, oscillators, phonons

I am familiar with the derivation of the speed of sound done in the style of, for example, this question:

[Diatomic chain and speed of sound](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/438307/)

I would like to derive that same result

$$
c^2=\frac{2ka^2}{m+M}
$$
Obtained in that problem using
$$
c= \lim_{q \to 0} \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial q}
$$
but instead I want to derive the speed of sound using the Newton-Laplace formula
$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}=c^2
$$
What I tried so far:

For the density I put delta functions at each mass
$$
\rho = \sum_n m_n \delta(x-u_n)
$$
where the $ n $ th particle has mass $ m_n $ and equilibrium position $ u_n $. Note that this has correct units since the units of a delta function are the inverse of the units of the argument. For pressure I'm using something like
$$
P= k( x_n-x_{n-1} ) 
$$
which has the right units so that $ P/\rho $ has units of speed squared but I need pressure to include some delta functions at each point without messing up the units. Perhaps a kronecker delta function would work?

I'm unsure of both my choice of $ P $ and of $ \rho $ and I don't see how to continue with the problem in any way that's likely to produce the $ a^2 $ factor I need in my answer.

This question is essentially equivalent to:

[Speed of Sound in 1D using pressure and density](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/312129/)

since diatomic vs monatomic is not important. However I don't find the answer posted there to be very useful.

Perhaps If I Fourier expand $ x_n $ as
$$
x_n = \int_{- \pi}^\pi \frac{1}{2\pi} dq x_q e^{iqn-i\omega_q t}
$$
and use that
$$
\omega_q= \frac{k}{\mu}\pm \sqrt{ \frac{k^2}{\mu^2}-\frac{4k^2}{mM} sin^2(qa) }
$$
To reiterate: how do I derive the speed of sound in a 1d chain using the formula
$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}=c^2
$$
Have I chosen my density and pressure correctly? Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: It might be worth remembering that the Newton-Laplace formula you provide is a macroscopic formula, and is only strictly valid for continua.  I would recommend you define a macroscopic density and pressure (averaging over large numbers of elements), and then apply the formula to those quantities.